# Specifying an informative prior in a simple brms model

Tags: r, brms

I am trying to understand how to specify (implement) an informed prior with `brms` in `R`. For example, a simple linear mixed effect model like:

```
DV ~ F1 * F2 + (1|Participant)
```

`F1` and `F2` are both two-level factors. I am only *interested* to test if one level of, say, `F2` is significantly higher than another, either as the main effect only, or in interaction (e.g., a significantly stronger/steeper difference). In effect, this would be a case of one-sided testing, which should be more "meaningful" in the Bayesian framework. For the rest of the model, I do not have any specific prior expectations.

How should I define my informative prior with `brms`?

Comment: Doing a one-sided test is a perfectly reasonable request, but I don't think you would do it by setting an informed prior. (An informed prior that excluded negative values would say that you **assumed** the effect would be positive, not that you were interested in testing the probability that it was positive, or larger than a specified positive threshold (i.e. "positive and large").